# Override TreeNode in databound TreeView?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I know that if I subclass TreeNode then I can add it to the Nodes collection within a TreeView. However the TreeView that I am working on at the moment is databound, is there any way to tell the TreeView what type its nodes should be?

Thnaks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just subclass TreeView and override the CreateNode method.

```
public class PermissionsTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override TreeNode CreateNode()
    {
        return new PermissionsTreeNode();
    }
}
```